# Using Stat module on multiple files and using a map

Tags: ansible

I am using the stat module to check for multiple files and register the result

```yaml
  - name: Check if ST was successfully stopped
    stat:
      path: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - /var/run/sshd.pid
      - /var/run/httpd.pid
      - /var/run/db.pid
    register: status_stopped
```

When these files are not found or `stat` states they do not exist, I want to perform a task like so:

```yaml
  - name: Clear out Axway tmp directory
    shell: rm -rf /var/tmp/*
    when: not status_stopped.results|map(attribute='stat.exists.false')|bool
```

When the files exists, the step still executes. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: "_Is there a better way to handle this?_", indeed, yes. [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html), [`systemd` module – Manage systemd units](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html), etc. ...

Answer (score 1):

As a direct answer to your question:

```yaml
  - name: Pretend to do something when all files are absent
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "All files are absent. Doing what I have to do"
    when: not (status_stopped.results | map(attribute='stat.exists')) is all
```

Reference: [Testing if a list value is true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true)

To go further:

1. Removing files with `shell` is a bad practice. Use the [`file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html) with `state: absent`
2. Checking a service is running by presence of a file in `/var/run` is a bad practice. Register your services correctly in your OS and as already reported by @U880D in comments, use [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html), [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html), [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html), [`sysvinit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sysvinit_module.html)... depending on your environment and requirement.